# Remplazar una imagen vieja con php y MySqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Sé como agregar una imagen y guardarla en mi DB de Mysql, pero a la hora de hacer el `UPDATE` de la imagen no la reemplaza.

```
<?php 
session_start();

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trigoyponque2017");

$id           = $_GET['id'];
$titulo       = $_POST['titulo'];
$descripcion  = $_POST['descripcion'];
$foto         = $_FILES["foto"]["name"];
$ruta         = $_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"];
$destino      = "../productos/".$foto;
copy($ruta,$destino);

if($foto != ""){
  $editar   = "UPDATE producto 
  SET titulo= '$titulo', descripcion = '$descripcion' WHERE id= '$id'";
} else {
  $editar   = "UPDATE producto
  SET titulo= '$titulo', descripcion = '$descripcion', foto = '$destino' WHERE id= '$id'";
}

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$editar);

if(!$resultado){
  echo "ERROR.";
}else{
  echo "Producto editado correctamente.";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

En mi base de datos sólo se ve la ruta, pero no la foto que se ha subido.

[image: Base de datos...]

Answer (score 1):

Realizar un `var_dump` de `$_FILES['foto']`  por qué al parecer no está definido es posible que la foto no esté subiendo o el `input` no se llame foto.

```
var_dump( $_FILES[ 'foto' ] );
```

Por otro lado no uses `copy` para mover el archivo usa: [`move_uploaded_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

También valida antes `$_FILES['foto']` con `isset` y asegúrate que el `name` sea solo el nombre del archivo y no toda la ruta.

```
if ( isset( $_FILES[ 'foto' ] ) ) { ...
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Cambie el copy por el  move_uploaded_file y además añadí un mejor filtro. Muchisimas gracias. n.n